# How can I provision the search center to my visual studio solution?

Tags: search, 2013, enterprise-search, provisioning, out-of-the-box

How can I provision the search center to my visual studio solution? I have edited my page layout and master page to be able to have the search center in the maincontent of my site collection.

Maby there is a webpart I could just add in my modules element.xml?

Something like following:

```
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
        <webParts>
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
           .............
        </webPart>
        </webParts>
        ]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Or is the Search Center in a feature that I could add the feature in my webtemplates onet.xml?

Any kind of help is appreciated alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Search Center is a dedicate site template, with its dedicated onet / webtemp entries & definition.

You could easily add one to your site collection by creating a subsite with the template `SRCHCENTERLITE#0` / `SRCHCENTERLITE#1` or `SRCHCEN#0`.

Alternatively, you could inject the key search webpart within a dedicated page like in your code sample. You'll need the Core Search Result WebPart, Search Query, Search Paging & Search Refinment to mimic what's available in a search center.

Comment: How exacly can add SRCHCEN#0 in my site collection? I added it as my basetemplatename and basetemplateid which is 50. What else?

Comment: I think Francois meant you could create a Feature Receiver which will automatically create the Search Center when your feature is activated. Keep in mind, it's a completely separate site (as it's a site template), so when you're in a site and you activate this feature, it'll create a new site somewhere, from the Search Centre template.

Comment: Thanks James. My answer was a little bit short on description but indeed, either a feature receiver, or if you are working with publishing site definition, you can add one to your provisioning template.